# Highlight a cell if there is a specific word in the cell's text

Tags: excel, vba

I want to red highlight all cells that contain the word "Color" and "Width".

With the code I have, I enter the cell's value. I want to enter the word "Color" and "Width".

```
Sub test()    

aaa = InputBox("Enter value 1:")
bbb = InputBox("Enter value 2:")

Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabell").UsedRange

For Each cell In myrange.Cells

    If cell.Value = aaa Or cell.Value = bbb Then
        cell.Interior.Color = 255
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Like`.

**edit** - updated to allow for multiple terms to be entered (untested)

```
dim terms as new collection, term, deleteMe as boolean

do
    term = Trim(InputBox("Enter value (leave blank to end entry)"))
    if len(term)>0 then
        terms.add term
    else
        exit do
    end if
loop

if terms.count=0 then exit sub '<< no terms to check for

For Each cell In myrange.Cells

    deleteMe = true

    for each term in terms
        if not cell.value like term & "*" then
            deleteMe = false 
            exit for
        end if
    next term

    if deleteMe then cell.value = ""
next cell
```

Comment: Hi Tim!  Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I want what I type in to be left and the rest to be deleted. So if for example if I write: Object and Color then the table should look like the picture I have sent.

ie everything else should be deleted, so what remains is Bara Object, and Color. ie door1, door2 .... and Yellow, green ....

So instead of marking what I write with the color red, it should - Delete all other information

Comment: please i need help with another thing:

My code looks at the forgotten seen now:

Comment: Sub test()


aaa = InputBox("Which object information do you want to display:")



Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabell").UsedRange


For Each cell In myrange.Cells


If Not (cell.Value Like aaa & "*") Then
    cell.Value = ""
End If



Next


End Sub

Comment: But the problem with it is that you can write in once what it should keep. That is, the user can only enter once and then it will delete everything except what it writes.
But I want the user to be able to type in several times before removing everything else. That is, I want the user to write, for example: Objects, Traps AND SEN if it writes the word END then the program should end up asking him, If he wants to write several things.

So I want the user to be able to write several things and then when he is finished writing END and then it stops asking him.